# Question about group generator and order of a number

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find all generators of $\Bbb{Z_{22}}$
>
> Solution: Since $\operatorname{ord(\mathbb Z_{22})} = 22,$ if $a$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z_{22},$ then $\operatorname{ord(a)}$ must equal $22$. Now let $b$ be a generator of $\mathbb Z_{22}$, then $b = 1^b = b \ldots$

The proof above is incomplete. How does $b = 1^b = b$ follow from the assumption that $b$ is a generator of $\Bbb{Z_{22}}$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think by exponentiation, they mean repeating the group operation, which in this case is addition. It's rather confusing, but kind of makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1^b=b$ is true for all $b \in \Bbb{Z}_{22}$, not just generators. This is because this proof uses an odd definition of exponentiation. In group theory, exponentiation is repeating the group operation. In this case, the group operation is addition, so exponentiation is repeated addition. For example, $1^2=1+1=2$.

This can seem very odd and greatly unintuitive at times, which is why often, you will see the notation $b \cdot 1$ used for abelian/addition groups like $\Bbb{Z}_{22}$ instead of exponentiation. However, exponentiation for addition groups can come up from time to time, so it's good to know what this notation is talking about.

Comment: you have a knack for explaining things :)

Comment: @Matt Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

In general, for a cyclic group $\langle a \rangle$ of order $n$, we have that the order of $a^k$ is:

$\dfrac{n}{\gcd(k,n)}$

When the group is written additively, we write $ka$ (meaning $a+a+\cdots+a$ ($k$ times)), instead of $a^k$ (meaning $a\cdot a \cdots a$ ($k$ times)) (the "rules of exponents" stay the same:

$(a^k)^m = a^{km}$ becomes $m(ka) = (km)a$ and:

$(a^k)(a^m) = a^{k+m}$ becomes $(ka) + (ma) = (k+m)a$-this is just notation, honest).

In $\Bbb Z_{22}$, we have $a = 1$, and $n = 22$, so the order of $k = k1$ is:

$\dfrac{22}{\gcd(k,22)}$.

A generator must have order $22$, so we want $\gcd(k,22) = 1$.

So the generators are:

$\{1,3,5,7,9,13,15,17,19,21\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the group operation in $\mathbb Z_{22}$ is $+$. So $1^b$ really means $b\cdot 1$.

The generators of $\mathbb Z_{22}$, would be equivalence classes of numbers coprime to $22$.